# Install jspdf@1.5.3 give error : undefined ls-remote -h -t ssh://git@github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js.git

Tags: angular, git, jspdf

When I try to install jspdf (npm i jspdf@1.5.3) version 1.3.3 (latest) to my Angular 7 application it's gives following error.

```
undefined ls-remote -h -t > ssh://git@github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js.git
```

[image]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+undefined+ls-remote

Comment: I updated the git version (git version 2.21.0.windows.1), it's fixed the issue. Thank you @phd